# Why is Kubernetes K8s not in official Ubuntu repos?

Tags: 22.04, repository, kubernetes

I am aware of the more generic version of this question, found here:

[Why is some software not in the official Ubuntu repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/q/882211/101335)

However, I would like to ask about Kubernetes in particular.

I am wonder why some very popular package does not add in official Ubuntu repo? is there any way to add this to official repo?

For example I found `kubectl` in [Debian repo](https://packages.debian.org/source/bullseye/kubernetes) but I do not know why found this in `universe`?

Comment: The Golang ecosystem is not very friendly to Debian/Red Hat packaging, and for complex systems like k8s with rapid release cycles (multiple times a year) being frozen into an LTS system like Ubuntu or Debian really doesn't make sense. Most people using K8s wouldn't want that. Put simply, there's no actual market, aside from the random hobbyist.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the kubectl snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu by running the following command:

```
sudo snap install microk8s --classic
sudo snap install kubectl --classic
sudo snap install kubelet --classic
sudo snap install kubeadm --classic
```

snap packages are available for all versions of kubectl from 1.5 to 1.28. Dozens of other kubernetes snap packages are also available. To list them all run `snap find kubernetes` .

Comment: Why we cannot use `apt install` ?

Comment: I believe `kubectl` isn't actually Kubernetes itself, but only a management interface. Whereas `microk8s` is a single-node Kubernetes instance.

Comment: But I need `kubeadm`, `kubectl`, `kubelet`, ... package separately in Debian form, for installing large scale Kubernetes in ubuntu servers

Comment: kubeadm, kubectl, and kubelet are all packaged as snap packages in Ubuntu. I revised my answer accordingly.

Comment: @karel Ok, My question is why Ubuntu does not provide these packages in debian form?

Comment: Because Kubernetes is being aggressively developed most users prefer to install recent versions. `apt` doesn't update as aggressively as snap, so packages with a fast update schedule like Firefox are packaged as snap packages in Ubuntu. That's good for Ubuntu users like me who sometimes need the latest version of a software.